# Java JDBC Only Inserts Nulls into MySQL Table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL table via a JDBC connection in Java. I can establish a connection. However, my code only inserts null values for all my columns. I am using dummy data in my prepared statement and expect to see non-null values.

Any thoughts or guidance as to what may be going on? I am new to JBDC and Java.

Here is how I create my table:

```
    drop table market_data.abc;
create table market_data.abc(
`v` int,
`w` int
)
;
```

Here is how I create a connection:

```
    public static Connection ConnectToDB() throws Exception {

        // register driver
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());

        // create database url
        mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + databaseName + "?characterEncoding=" + encoding
                + "&&useUnicode=" + unicode; 

        // create connection
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, userName, password);

        // print connection status message
        System.out.println("Connection established......");

        // return database connection
        return con;
    }
```

Here is where I insert data:

```
void insertRecords() {
        try {

            // Establish Connection
            Connection con = cc.ConnectToDB();

            // Set the query structure
            String insertString = "INSERT INTO abc values (" + "v=?,w=?)";

            // Set prepared statement
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(insertString);

            // set values to variables
            int v1 = 2;
            int w1 = 3;

            // set values to statement
            statement.setInt(1, v1);
            statement.setInt(2, w1);

            // execute the insert operation; 
            statement.executeUpdate();

            // print status message for record insertion
            System.out.println("New Records inserted.....");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is what I see when I do a Select * from the CLI:

```
 v    | w    |
+------+------+
| NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL |
+------+------+
```

Here are my MySQL character set variables:

```
show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                     |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-8.0.20-macos10.15-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your SQL syntax is incorrect and should have thrown an exception. It should be `INSERT INTO abc (v,w) VALUES (?,?)`.

Comment: Making that adjustment worked. Weird that SQL exception was not thrown. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You are inserting the result of the equals predicate between the column `v` and the parameter. It looks like at time of evaluation, `v` evaluates to `null`, so the result of equals is also `null`.

Answer (score -2):

try to replace insertString value with this one value

```
String insertString = "INSERT INTO abc values (v=?,w=?)";
```

and take care that INSERT statement has tow writing types.

first type is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

second one is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Comment: you can visit this link to check the difference between insert types
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Since the table is simple, I used the second one. I also updated the  insertString as suggested but no luck.

Comment: I'm not 100% - if I was getting an error it would be caught by at least Exception, right? To be safe I added SQLException to my catch clause with e.getMessage(); but no luck.

Comment: ah, I see. I wrapped e.getMessage() with a println. Thanks for explaining that distinction to me. Also, I am getting no error when executing this code. I believe that makes sense - rows are being inserted into my table (so no malformed SQL or Java Syntax errors). It is just that the rows inserted contain nulls as opposed to the expected data values.

Comment: The `insertString` shown here is identical to the OP's, just without the concatenation, and both are incorrect.